# How to make the function work after removing and adding it again

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm not sure what is the correct title for this. My problem is that after clicking and changing the title, It doesn't fire up the `on click` anymore.

Please see the fiddle below:

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gnwwgbkr/)

**HTML**

```
<h2><span class="ss-icon ss-repeat"></span> 
        <span id="campaignEditTitle">Click Me to Edit <small><span class="ss-write"></span></small></span>
        <small> &nbsp; 3 Messages (2 active, 1 draft)
        </small>
      </h2>
```

**JS**

```
$('#campaignEditTitle').on('click', function(){
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).replaceWith('<input id="campaignInputTitle" type="text" value="' + title + '">');
        console.log(title);

        $('#campaignInputTitle').keypress(function(e) {
            if(e.which == 13) {
                var newTitle = $(this).val();
                $(this).replaceWith('<span id="campaignEditTitle">' + newTitle + '<small><span class="ss-write"></span></small>');
            }
        });
        $('#campaignInputTitle').on('blur', function(){
            var newTitle = $(this).val();
            $(this).replaceWith('<span id="campaignEditTitle">' + newTitle + '<small><span class="ss-write"></span></small>');
        });        
    });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By using event delegation:

```
$('body').on('click','#campaignEditTitle', function(){
    var title = $(this).text();
    $(this).replaceWith('<input id="campaignInputTitle" type="text" value="' + title + '">');
    console.log(title);

});

$('body').on('keypress','#campaignInputTitle',function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            var newTitle = $(this).val();
            $(this).replaceWith('<span id="campaignEditTitle">' + newTitle + '<small><span class="ss-write"></span></small>');
        }
});

$('body').on('blur','#campaignInputTitle', function(){
        var newTitle = $(this).val();
        $(this).replaceWith('<span id="campaignEditTitle">' + newTitle + '<small><span class="ss-write"></span></small>');
});
```